# How do I select multiple time ranges in the same dataset to form a new sub-dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, slice

[Example of sub-dataset1 (desired output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9Luo.png)  [First 20 rows of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6NpZ.png)

Hello everyone, I have a rather convoluted dataset which i need to get some help with. I am trying to figure out how i can select multiple time ranges and dates in my dataset and bundle them together into sub-datasets which represent different activities, for comparison. For example: All data between these time ranges:

(08:42:11 & 08:42:38; 08:42:42 & 08:42:44; and 08:43:18 & 08:44:02) sub dataset 1 (3 peoples results from walking)

(08:44:53 & 08:45:03; 08:45:22 & 08:47:07; and 08:47:08 & 08:47:10) sub dataset 2 (3 peoples results from running)

The different time ranges here (just used as examples) represent different people participating in an activity. Each sub-dataset represents a different activity(walking and running). So, basically what i am trying to do it collate the data from each participant for each activity to then compare against each other. I would also need to specify the date (23rd in this example) as my actual dataset runs over multiple days.

There are articles on multiple dates and looking between 1 time range but i havent been able to find any literature on creating a dataframe with multiple time-slices so to speak.

So to summarise:
The instrument ran continuously over the few days providing one big dataset which now needs splitting up by time/date, picking out each participants results for an activity and placing the combined data into a new subdataset which now represents all the results for that activity. And so on for each activity. I can then compare these against one another in boxplots or other analyses (i.e. walking vs running).

Any guidance here would be greatly appreciated!

```
f = h5py.File('data.h5', 'r')
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['AF','Fl1','Fl2'])
df['AF']=f['data']['AF'][()]
df['Fl1']=f['data']['Fl1'][()]
df['Fl2']=f['data']['Fl2'][()]
df=df.set_index('Time')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit='s')
df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
df=df.dropna()
```

Comment: Please provide example of the desired output.

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting! I want to be able to split my dataset up by multiple time ranges and dates (see above) which i can then use to compare in box plots and other analyses. Using the above as my example, lets say i have 3 people that perform two tasks, walking and running. I kept the timer running through the whole experiment and recorded timings for each person. So now i want to group together each of the 3 peoples results for walking into 1 and likewise for the running, so that i may compare the results for walking vs running. I hope that clears up what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry I am still unsure if I get it. Do you have any code? Please include a demo of input data + desire output. It is much easier to understand than word description.

Comment: Unfortunately i cant provide that as there are no examples out there that i've been able to find and if there was one i probably wouldnt have needed to make this post for help. All i've done is load in a file and create a dataframe with time as the index, AF column, Fl1 column, and Fl2 column (see attached picture). Now i want to be able to split that data up as per my comment above.

Comment: I am not asking for an example out in the wild, but an example of the output of say your 20-row demo data, because I cannot imagine what the output looks like exactly.

Comment: Neither can i, hence asking the question. Again, all i can do is describe what i'm trying to achieve. If i were able to give a demo output i probably wouldn't need to make this post. I'm looking to make multiple sub-datasets (df2, walking etc.. whatever you want to call them). In each dataset I need there to be the combined data from each participant taking part in that activity. To do that, I need to select all the data in between the multiple time ranges provided and add them to the new sub-dataset. I then need to repeat for the other activities. I'm not sure how else i can explain it?

Comment: Thank you for your comments and time by the way, i'm just struggling to find a way of communicating what i'm after i think.

Comment: So given your 20-row input data, what is your expected output?

Comment: I guess another way of saying it could be: Walking/df2 = (time/date range and all data corresponding to that range for participant 1) & (data participant 2) & (data participant 3) etc.. Running/df3= (time/date range and all data within that range for participant 1) & (data participant 2) & (data participant 3)

Comment: And therefore say i want to compare the results for column(variable) AF between walking and running in a plot, i'd be comparing all the peoples 'AF' results from walking vs all the results from running which i could then interpret.

Comment: So given your 20-row input data, what would the output be if you do it in hand calculation?

Comment: I'm not calculating anything, i'm just splicing chunks of the data together based on time/date.

Comment: Then please kindly show us what these chunks contain.

Comment: Yes i've spliced together in powerpoint what subdataset 1(walking) would look like. Please see attached image

Comment: Have you been able to see the desired output image i uploaded?